# Use Ramda to collect JSON data from many files

Tags: node.js, promise, ramda.js

Pushing myself to use Ramda on a small Node project, for the first time, and I've gotten to a hard part.  How can I write the code below with Ramda?

```
const dataObject = {};
const promises = [];

for (let i = 0; i < myTableNames.length; i++) {
    const tableName = myTableNames[i];
    const newPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(`./tables/${filename}.json`, (err, content) => {
            if (err) { 
                return reject();
            }
            dataObject[tableName] = JSON.parse(content);
            return resolve();
        });
    });
    promises.push(newPromise);
}

Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
  console.log(dataObject);
});
```

Comment: Is using `https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra` an option?  If so, it'll make things easier since the `fs` methods return promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using node v.8 you could do it like this. [Demo](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?%2F%2F%20fake%20read%20file%0Aconst%20readFile%20%3D%20file%20%3D%3E%20new%20Promise%28resolve%20%3D%3E%20setTimeout%28resolve%2C%20500%2C%20%60%7B%22fileName%22%3A%20%22%24%7Bfile%7D%22%7D%60%29%29%0Aconst%20getFilePath%20%3D%20filename%20%3D%3E%20%60.%2Ftables%2F%24%7Bfilename%7D.json%60%0Aconst%20loadFileContents%20%3D%20pipe%28getFilePath%2C%20pipeP%28readFile%2C%20JSON.parse%29%29%0Aconst%20myTableNames%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%27table1%27%2C%0A%20%20%27table2%27%2C%0A%20%20%27table3%27%2C%0A%20%20%27table4%27%0A%5D%0A%0APromise.all%28map%28loadFileContents%2C%20myTableNames%29%29%0A%20%20.then%28zipObj%28myTableNames%29%29%0A%20%20.then%28console.log%29%0A)

```
// promisify fs.readFile
const readFile = require('util').promisify(fs.readFile)
const getFilePath = tableName => `./tables/${tableName}.json`
const loadFileContents = pipe(getFilePath, pipeP(readFile, JSON.parse))

// 1. Map each table name into promise that resolves with
//    parsed file content
// 2. Wait for all
// 3. Build object using table names as keys and contents as
//    as values
Promise.all(map(loadFileContents, myTableNames))
  .then(zipObj(myTableNames))
  .then(console.log)
```

Comment: Two good solutions — I chose this one because I learned about zipObj from it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With `fs-extra`:

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');

const readFile = fileName => fs.readFile(`./tables/${fileName}.json`);
const buildResults = (files) => {
  const build = (acc, json, idx) => R.assoc(myTableNames[idx], JSON.parse(json), acc);
  return R.reduce(build, {}, files);
}

Promise.all(R.map(readFile, myTableNames))
  .then(buildResults)
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: @ScottSauyet Assuming this would be wrapped in a function returning a promise.

Comment: Looks good, although the last line probably could just read `. then(console.log)`